# Dropdownlist,CheckBox in MVC Grid in flat mode not in Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm struggling to create a grid with two columns as bound columns and other two columns as dropdown and checkbox and last column is a column with update button.

I need to change the values of dropdown and checkbox and then need to store those values in the database while clicking the update button. I don't know how to save the changed values of ddl and checkbox in the database.

Thanks in advance.